# AttributeError: dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, AttachDebuggerTracing): symbol not found

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, homebrew, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to use the debugger in vs code (mac os big sur) with no success.
I'm on the m1 macbook air. vs code insiders version.
I've tried with all these python interpreters:

3.9.6 - /opt/homebrew/bin/python3
3.9.1 - /usr/local/bin/python3
3.8.2 - /usr/bin/python3
2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python

I've tried with this launch.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the error that I always get:

```
 /usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/arch0n/.vscode-insiders/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1053846006/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 50295 -- /Users/arch0n/Desktop/py-w3schools/2.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/arch0n/.vscode-insiders/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1053846006/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "/Users/arch0n/.vscode-insiders/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1053846006/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 444, in main
    run()
  File "/Users/arch0n/.vscode-insiders/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1053846006/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 267, in run_file
    start_debugging(target)
  File "/Users/arch0n/.vscode-insiders/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1053846006/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 257, in start_debugging
    debugpy.connect(options.address, access_token=options.adapter_access_token)
  File "/Users/arch0n/.vscode-insiders/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1053846006/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/common/compat.py", line 208, in kwonly_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/arch0n/.vscode-insiders/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1053846006/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/__init__.py", line 135, in connect
    return api.connect(address, access_token=access_token)
  File "/Users/arch0n/.vscode-insiders/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1053846006/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/api.py", line 143, in debug
    log.reraise_exception("{0}() failed:", func.__name__, level="info")
  File "/Users/arch0n/.vscode-insiders/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1053846006/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/api.py", line 141, in debug
    return func(address, settrace_kwargs, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/arch0n/.vscode-insiders/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1053846006/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/api.py", line 276, in connect
    _settrace(host=host, port=port, client_access_token=access_token, **settrace_kwargs)
  File "/Users/arch0n/.vscode-insiders/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1053846006/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/api.py", line 47, in _settrace
    return pydevd.settrace(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/arch0n/.vscode-insiders/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1053846006/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 2696, in settrace
    _locked_settrace(
  File "/Users/arch0n/.vscode-insiders/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1053846006/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 2819, in _locked_settrace
    py_db.enable_tracing(py_db.trace_dispatch, apply_to_all_threads=True)
  File "/Users/arch0n/.vscode-insiders/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1053846006/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 1039, in enable_tracing
    pydevd_tracing.SetTrace(thread_trace_func)
  File "/Users/arch0n/.vscode-insiders/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1053846006/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd_tracing.py", line 83, in SetTrace
    if set_trace_to_threads(tracing_func, thread_idents=[thread.get_ident()], create_dummy_thread=False) == 0:
  File "/Users/arch0n/.vscode-insiders/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1053846006/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd_tracing.py", line 349, in set_trace_to_threads
    result = lib.AttachDebuggerTracing(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 387, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 392, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, AttachDebuggerTracing): symbol not found
```

arch0n is my user directory.

Comment: same problem on Big Sur 11.5 on Mac Mini M1. Never seen anything like it before

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue on Big Sur on MacBook Pro M1, but I'm not using the insiders version of VSCode

Comment: I've just checked now and so far the problem doesn't show up anymore on my system.
I will keep  an eye on it and give you an update if the problem shows up again. If you still experience the problem, downgrading the vs code python extension seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed the same issue I was having by rolling back to the prior version of ms-python.python extension.  The problem seems to be in the extension and has yet to be resolved.

Comment: This worked for me. Downgrading to ms-python.python v2021.6.944021595 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading to ms-python.python v2021.6.944021595 works.
I used the Uninstall menu in the Python extension
and picked v2021.6.944021595.